# How to estimate the computation overhead of ECDSA?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, pairings

I am using ECDSA as a digital signature scheme. Using [Charm](https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/index.html), I got the timing for the multiplication, exponentiation, and pairing operations; they take 0.005,  9, and 4.4 ms respectively. I want to estimate the computation overhead to sign and verify a message. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Have you tried yourself to map it to the operations that are specified for ECDSA?

Comment: I am new to crypto. I am learning. could you please help me to map that.

Comment: I don't see you listed as one of the authors of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.04666.pdf) which list explicitly these timings for the given operations. Generally we do require you to put in some effort other than to copy some data and hastily write a question around it, posting it before even proofreading it.

Comment: yes, I got the numbers form that paper

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. The signing approximately took 2 multiplication operations. while the verification algorithm costs 4  multiplication operations. I used the ECDSA from Wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm

Comment: This paper lists the results on the MNT1224 curve; we typically don't use that curve to do ECDSA; won't you be better off looking for the benchmark on ECDSA on a curve you'll use, on a processor you'll use?